# What IE version should you install to check CSS compatibility on IE with a Mac?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm trying to fix my css on IE, and I want to check to see if it's working. What version should I install and from where?

Answer (score 4):

Different versions of IE behave differently. If you care about all versions, you'll have to install them all.

IE doesn't run natively on a Mac. You'll either need to use a virtualization program like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (which itself is free, but you still need a copy of Windows) to produce a virtual Windows environment, or use services like [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) that will produce images taken in IE for you (but they're often very busy and therefore slow).

Comment: +1 "IE doesn't run natively on a Mac." And in the old days when it did, that was a completely different version of IE, so not very useful for testing compatibility.

Comment: The rendering engine for IE mac was a direct port of MSHTML.  I remember all the #ifdef MAC and #ifdef UNIX (it also ran on Solaris at one point) lines in the code.  So it *would* have been useful for testing, if it ever made it past IE 5 or whatever it was.

Comment: That is weird. I remember to have heard that CSS support for the mac was much better than for windows at one point.

Answer (score 1):

IE8, because it's stable and has IE7 compatible view mode.
It doesn't run on Mac OS, you will need to run it in Virtual Machine (VMWare, Virtualbox or Parallels).

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use a VM, as @Matchu told in his answer.

But if you can't, this is pretty good one:

https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html